# Do Pine Bark Nuggets stop weeds from growing in a lawn?

Tags: lawn, mulch

I have a bare area in my lawn where weeds grow fast. I want to buy many bags of nuggets to cover the area to stop the weeds.

Do pine bark nuggets stop weeds from growing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean bare areas of soil producing lots of weed growth of varying sorts, it depends which plants are growing as to how effective bark chips (pine bark nugget) will be. That said, any weed smothering mulch should be 3-4 inches deep, but there are some pernicious weeds that will still grow through regardless. You can use membrane beneath the chips for better weed prevention, but again, certain plants (Equisetum, Japanese Knotweed) will puncture through weed membrane too.